# How to construct subclasses of Immutable.Record?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, immutable.js

```
class Event extends Immutable.Record {
  constructor(text) {
    super({text: text, timestamp: Date.now()});
  }
}
```

Calling `new Event()` seems to return a constuctor function:

```
new Event('started').toString()
```

> "function Record(values){ if(values instanceof RecordType){ return
>   values;}
>
> if(!(this instanceof RecordType)){ return new RecordType(values);}
>
> if(!hasInitialized){ hasInitialized=true; var
>   keys=Object.keys(defaultValues); setProps(RecordTypePrototype,keys);
>   RecordTypePrototype.size=keys.length; RecordTypePrototype._name=name;
>   RecordTypePrototype._keys=keys;
>   RecordTypePrototype._defaultValues=defaultValues;}
>
> this._map=Map(values);}"

Whereas calling the function returns the expected output:

```
new Event('started')().toString()
```

> "Record { "text": "started", "timestamp": 1453374580203 }"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Immutable.Record "[Creates a new Class which produces Record instances](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record).", in other words it's a function in itself which you pass the allowed keys and returns a class you can extend;

```
class Event extends Immutable.Record({text:'', timestamp:''}) {
  constructor(text) {
    super({text: text, timestamp: Date.now()});
  }
}

> new Event('started').toString()
Event { "text": "started", "timestamp": 1453376445769 }
```

Comment: This is a great answer but I wish I could do it in plain, browser-ready (er, IE-ready) JS!

Comment: @mosolgo You can always transpile the code from ES6 to some older flavor of javascript. Can f.ex. try online repl of babel at https://babeljs.io/repl/

Comment: So what if I wanted to further extend the `Event` class by having a more specific version? Something like an `HttpEvent` that has a URL property or something. Can I just extend that as normal?