# Immutable.js Record with (default) unique id

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I want to create Immutable.js Records that have a (more or less) unique key. Something like this:

```
import { Record } from 'immutable'

var MyRecord = Record({
    key: Math.random().toString(),
    name: ""
})
```

Is this possible? I've tried it and all records have the same key. I'm importing `MyRecord` like this:

```
import { MyRecord } from '../model/MyRecord'
```

and create new records like this

```
var r = new MyRecord(data)
```

where `data` is a json object.

I could add the key manually after creating the new record of course, but I'd prefer to find a way to automate this.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34922916/893780).

Comment: @robertklep That works, thanks! (if you put it in an answer, I'll accept it)

Comment: It's not my answer really ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the great question and thanks to @robertklep for leading me to this answer by referring to this: [How to construct subclasses of Immutable.Record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34922321/how-to-construct-subclasses-of-immutable-record/34922916#34922916)

Adapting that answer to work with `id`s is slightly different: if there is an `id` given in the record, it won't generate one.

That's the only change really.

```js
// https://gist.github.com/jed/982883
// this can be any function that returns a string
function uuid(a){return a?(a^Math.random()*16>>a/4).toString(16):([1e7]+-1e3+-4e3+-8e3+-1e11).replace(/[018]/g,uuid)}

// this is the implementation you need
class MyRecordWithId extends Immutable.Record({
  id: '', // purposely have this empty string
  a: 'some a',
  b: 'some b'
}) {
  constructor(props) {
    super(Object.assign({}, props, {id: (props && props.id) || uuid()}))
  }
}

// this is a test to see the ID
const myRecord = new MyRecordWithId();
console.log('first record id: ', myRecord.id);

// these are tests to see if we can serialize the record and check if the ID is the same
const json = JSON.stringify(myRecord.toJS());
const js = JSON.parse(json);

const shouldHaveTheSameId = new MyRecordWithId().merge(Immutable.fromJS(js));

console.log('serialized id: ',shouldHaveTheSameId.id);

console.log('are the IDs the same?: ', myRecord.id === shouldHaveTheSameId.id ? 'yes' : 'no');

console.log('different id: ', new MyRecordWithId().id);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function createMyRecord (data){
  let record = new MyRecord(data)

  return record.set('key', Math.random().toString())
}
```