# Extending Record in Immutable.js

Tags: javascript, immutable.js, es6-class

I’m using Immuatable.js, and I wanted to extend Immutable.Record so I have a class that works identically but adds some default properties and functions.

Looking at the source, Record.js is an ES6 class that extends KeyedCollection but returns a function from the constructor.

https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/master/src/Record.js

I don't really understand the side effects of doing that.

Basically I'd like a FooRecord class where I can do this:

```
class FooifiedRecord extends FooRecord({
  name: '',
}){
  sayMyName(){
    return this.name;
  }
};
```

And it's equivalent to this:

```
class FooifiedRecord extends Immutable.Record({
  name: '',
  foo: '',
}) {
  doFoo(){
    return this.foo + ' bar';
  }
  sayMyName(){
    return this.name;
  }
}
```

But I'm not sure about the correct syntax.

EDIT: Not remotely similar to [How to construct subclasses of Immutable.Record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34922321/how-to-construct-subclasses-of-immutable-record), that covers basic use of Immutable.Record. I'm wondering how to extend it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to construct subclasses of Immutable.Record?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34922321/how-to-construct-subclasses-of-immutable-record)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't plan on instantiating your base class with **new** you can do what [justinko recommends here](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/issues/334#issuecomment-226097016):

```
import { Record } from 'immutable'

const Base = defaultValues => class extends Record({
  id: undefined,
  links: {},
  errors: {},
  ...defaultValues
}) {

}

class User extends Base({
  firstName: undefined,
  lastName: undefined
}) {
  fullName() {
    return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName 
  }
}
```